# Keycloak token still is valid after logout (spring boot)

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm using Keycloak and spring boot. the problem is when I log out session in Keycloak panel or with rest call in spring project, although the session will be removed from Keycloak, the user can still use that token to authenticate requests.
as I found, it seems that the Keycloak adapter doesn't check each token with the Keycloak server, is it true?
how can I solve this?

these are my codes and configs:

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class KeycloakSecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider
                = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(
                new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakPreAuthActionsFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilterBean(
            KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakSecurityContextRequestFilterBean(
            KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(HttpSessionManager.class)
    protected HttpSessionManager httpSessionManager() {
        return new HttpSessionManager();
    }


    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.csrf().disable().cors().and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/public/**", "/oauth/*", "/documents/**", "/images/**").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/digital/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/digital/offline/*").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/digital/admin/*").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://127.0.0.1:8180/auth
keycloak.realm=CustomerRealm
keycloak.resource=login-app
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.ssl-required = none
```

[image: config]

Comment: Configure and implement backchannel logout properly.

Comment: @JanGaraj could you please provide me some tips about it? this is error when the backchannel logout is called :o.k.a.s.a.KeycloakLogoutHandler.logout:62 - Cannot log out without authentication

Comment: Some API's do accept slightly old tokens, like a few minutes, this can in some frameworks be configured in the API. Google for "java clock skew"